# Clipping negative values to 0 in a dataframe column (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am doing a simple math equation of pandas series data frames, and some of the values are going negative when compiling a lot of the data. Is there code that I can add to ensure values of the subtraction math only go to minimum of zero? This is what I have so far:

```
deltaT['data'] = (deltaT['hws'] - deltaT['hwr'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: use deltaT.iloc[deltaT < 0, 'data'] = some value e.g. 0

Answer (score 10):

You could opt for [`clip_lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_lower.html) to do so in a single operation.

```
deltaT['data'] = (deltaT['hws'] - deltaT['hwr']).clip_lower(0)
```

Comment: clip_lower applies to data frame, not series. It returns AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'clip_lower'

Comment: @branwen85 in the question, you can see that they have a dataframe. You can also just use `np.clip`.

Comment: clip_lower() is deprecated since version 0.24.0: Use clip(lower=threshold) instead.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html

Answer (score 5):

You can create `deltaT['data']` and then use `df.loc` to set the negative values to 0.

```
deltaT['data'] = (deltaT['hws'] - deltaT['hwr'])
deltaT.loc[deltaT['data'] < 0, 'data'] = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
simple

```
deltaT['data'] = deltaT.eval('(hws - hwr) * (hws > hwr)')
```

---

Consider `deltaT`

```
deltaT = pd.DataFrame(dict(hws=[5, 8], hwr=[8, 5]))

deltaT.assign(data=deltaT.eval('(hws - hwr) * (hws > hwr)'))

   hwr  hws  data
0    8    5     0
1    5    8     3
```

---

**Option 2**
Same as option 1, but using numpy arrays

```
r, s = (deltaT[c].values for c in ['hwr', 'hws'])
deltaT.assign(data=(s - r) * (s > r))

   hwr  hws  data
0    8    5     0
1    5    8     3
```

---

**Option 3**
creative attempt

```
deltaT.assign(data=deltaT.eval('hws - hwr').to_frame().assign(_=0).max(1))

   hwr  hws  data
0    8    5     0
1    5    8     3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
deltaT['data'] = (deltaT['hws'] - deltaT['hwr']).apply(lambda x: max(x, 0))
```